# VimL: Function to cancel loading of plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Maybe the question title is not too specific. So let me explain:

This is for [this GitHub fork](https://github.com/Greduan/vim_number-toggle), for the [numbertoggle Vim plugin](https://github.com/jeffkreeftmeijer/vim-numbertoggle). Please check the structure of my fork, to understand what I mean.

What I need is a way to deactivate it, after it's been loaded. In other words, completely erase it off the charts if that function is called.

In other, other words. If the plugin is called, and I do `:call NumberToggleOff()` then it will disable it and act as Vim would normally function.

What would be a good way to achieve this? I've tried several methods, but none works.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would simply unmapping the trigger be what you want? e.g. `nunmap <c-m>`

Comment: That does seem to make sense. But as far as I can tell, if I call it once it's activated for good, which is what I want. So I don't think unmapping it will do any good. I will however try it and see how it goes. In the mean while, you think you could figure out a whole structure to achieve this? I think it's gonna be necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it can be done by surrounding autocommands by

```
augroup NumberToggle
    …
augroup END
```

and remembering `{lhs}` of the mapping. To disable it you then do

```
let s:plugin_lhs=exists('g:NumberToggleTrigger') ? g:NumberToggleTrigger : '<C-n>'
let g:numbertoggle={}
function! g:numbertoggle.unload()
    augroup NumberToggle
        autocmd!
    augroup END
    augroup! NumberToggle
    execute 'nunmap' s:plugin_lhs
    delfunction NumberToggle
    delfunction UpdateMode
    delfunction FocusGained
    delfunction FocusLost
    delfunction InsertLeave
    delfunction InsertEnter
    unlet g:numbertoggle
    unlet g:loaded_numbertoggle
    unlet g:insertmode g:focus
    unlet s:plugin_lhs
endfunction
" Then do :call g:numbertoggle.unload()
" Loading is done by resourcing numbertoggle
```

It would be much better if instead of using a bunch of `delfunction` calls you convert all function names to `g:numbertoggle.toggle`, `g:numbertoggle.update`, … and just leave `unlet g:numbertoggle`.

It completely undoes effect of the plugin, not just disables it.

Comment: I tried what you said, and I have run into just one problem: `E716: Key not present in Dictionary: source` `source` being the function name I'm using to put it back on. What can I do to fix this? You can check the latest version here: https://github.com/Greduan/vim_number-toggle/tree/on-off Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Also, if you would be so kind as to put your answer in one of the issues there, I would really appreciate it, helps me keep track of stuff, GitHub issues that is. :)

Comment: @Eduan You were not supposed to do this. Keep everything as-is, just put what I said before and after a list of autocommands (what you have in `.unload` regarding this issue is not making *any* sense without modifications of the autocommands list) and rename functions. You are having `E716` for a reason: when I said it undoes *everything* it meant it is really undoing everything, including global variables. You do `unlet g:numbertoggle` - you have no more `g:numbertoggle.source` function. Or remove `unlet g:numbertoggle` line and add augroup around autocommands.

Comment: Oh I see. Well, that was dumb (of me of course). Thanks for your answer, I will fix it and ask for you help again. ;)

Comment: @Eduan In the latter case it won’t undo *everything*, but it will disable the plugin. Also remove `!` from function definitions. At least for dictionary functions, doing `let g:numbertoggle={}` will effectively remove the functions (unless there are more references saved somewhere) so `!` makes no sense, it won’t ever redefine functions.

Comment: I see, I understand, I will remove the `!` from my dictionary functions. :) With 'in the latter case' you mean the case that I currently have? Sorry for stupid questions. ;P

Comment: @Eduan Nearly. The latter case described in a previous comment which effectively describes some minor bugfixes to what you currently have.

Comment: Ah I see, you mean the following: 'Or remove `unlet g:numbertoggle` line and add augroup around autocommands.' I will probably do this, since I just want to disable it, not destroy it. Thanks for your help, will probably be a couple of hours since I have other stuff to do, but nevertheless thank you. :)

Comment: @Eduan When writing complex plugin (not numbertoggle) about which you know it will require clean unloading (or if you just want to update that plugin without restarting vim) take a look at [frawor](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/frawor) framework. Following some simple rules (more complex in case you are using one of the interpreters support) you get unloading and clean reloading of your plugin for free. Rules are described in a README file. For mappings use interface described in 2. in **Advantages** section (or they won’t be unloaded/reloaded).

Comment: @Eduan Though beware of using “twoload” functionality, it will be removed in the near future as it is just a futile attempt to put everything into one file and delay loading at the same time instead of using built-in autoload (*frawor* and/or vim autoload, mainly the first) functionality and different files.

Comment: OK, thanks for the tips. I will probably not use the Frawor framework, because the original author wants something simple. But thanks anyway. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20762/discussion-between-eduan-and-zyx)